# Construction of the Hilbert Scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, line-bundles, hilbert-schemes

I am reading the book "Rational Curves on Algebraic Varieties" of János Kollár.  Definition-Proposition 1.2, begin like this:

Let $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ be a projective morphism and $\mathcal{O}(1)$ a $g$-ample line bundle. I would like to know what is a "$g$-ample line bundle".

Thank you a lot!

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VG

Comment: @Wojowu thank you!!!

Comment: Also EGA II, §4.6, page 89, http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1961__8__5_0/